# How to adjust the parameters of a Piecewise regression model in Matlab?

Tags: regression, modeling, matlab, computational-statistics, piecewise-linear

I have an existent piecewise regression model correlating the parameters X and Y as follows:
If X<0.1, then Y=0.744.
If X>=0.1 & X<=0.8, then Y=0.842-0.977*X.
If X>0.8, then Y=0.06.
The model was originally developed based on (X,Y) data pairs measured on one location. Now, I have new measured data from different location, and the model do not follow the actual X-Y relationship in the new location.
My question is how to adjust the coefficients of the model (not the breakpoints: 0.1 and 0.8) in Matlab, while keeping the polynomial orders the same, and keeping the model continuous (no jumps in estimated Y values)?
[image: Model]

Comment: What prevents you from applying the procedure used to obtain the original model?

Answer (score 1):

You need a predictor, $x^*$, say, which is $0$ for $x<0.1$, is $(x-0.1)$ for $0.1\leq x\leq 0.8$ and is $0.8-0.1=0.7$ for $x>0.8$. then a simple linear regression of $y$ on $x^*$ should achieve the required fit.

Comment: The requirement that $x^{*}(0.8)=0.7$ is mysterious, partly because the value of $0.7$ is immaterial (so long as it is nonzero).  It seems to create a strong connection to the previous regression solution, even though no such connection exists.  It therefore might be clearer to define $x^{*}$ *via* simple properties: namely, equal to zero at one end, equal to one at the other, and connecting the two parts continuously and linearly.  Are you perhaps trying to hint that the *prediction* from the first regression could serve as the *regressor* for the second?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your thoughts. I don't think this is mysterious, it's a matter of which simple properties you want and which you're prepared to give up.The simple property I felt it useful to retain is that in the linear section, the predictor is simply a shifted-version-of-$x$ - i.e. $(x-0.1)$ between $x=0.1$ and $x=0.8$. Consequently, rather than being some mystery, it's quite plain that $x-0.1$ is $0.8-0.1$ at $x=0.8$; continuity then requires it stay there. Your suggestion is certainly simpler in one sense but less simple in another:  ...ctd

Comment: ctd... if interest were to be on the rate of change of $y$ with $x$ in the middle section it would be handy to retain a 1:1 relationship with a slope in terms of the x-variable (e.g. if we had fit only data in the middle section we'd see a similar slope, rather than trying to compare with one in terms of scaled-units-of-$x$). I felt that was - at least potentially - an important consideration, though that's in part due to exposure to situations where just that was an issue. What I failed to do there was explain any of that thought process. I should probably write a little explaining it.

Comment: To be honest I hadn't even paid any attention to the y-axis values of either the red or the black parts of the plot; they played no part in the consideration of how to set up the $x^*$ -variable, which was driven entirely by the placement of the knots.

Comment: Yes, those explanations are informative and interesting!